# telegram web login widget /setdomain does not work

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to use the telegrom web login widget.

I have followed the instructions here:

https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login

And I have set up my bot and selected it with the BotFather, but when I enter /setdomain it just points me back to the url above. I don't seem to be able to actually configure my domain anywhere.

When I use the code snippet created on that page on my web site, it just displays:

Bot domain invalid.

Has anyone else had luck setting up telegram login on their site?

Answer (score 20):

So, it turns out the wording that the bot uses is a bit confusing:

Here is how the dialog goes, and how you need to respond to Botfather:

**Me:**

/setdomain

**Botfather:**

Choose a bot to set or change its linked domain. See Login Widget documentation for details:
https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login

**Me:**

@thenameofthe_bot

**BotFather:**

Link your website with your bot to use the Telegram Login Widget. Widget documentation:
https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login
Use /empty to remove.

**Me:**

https://www.thenameofmysite.com/

**BotFather:**

Success! Domain updated. /help

---

The mistakes I might have been making were:
a) Not using the @ sign for the bot?
b) Following the link to the site and expecting to see further configuration there, rather than typing in the website after that confusing response.