# Telegram login widget return "bot domain invalid" in my mvc app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I use telegram login widget in  MVC App , and follow steps as in post
[telegram-web-login-widget-setdomain-does-not-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51893388/telegram-web-login-widget-setdomain-does-not-work)

***Steps As in Post***

> Here is how the dialog goes, and how you need to respond to Botfather:
>
> Me:
>
> /setdomain
>
> Botfather:
>
> Choose a bot to set or change its linked domain. See Login Widget   documentation for details: https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login
>
> Me:
>
> @thenameofthe_bot
>
> BotFather:
>
> Link your website with your bot to use the Telegram Login Widget. Widget > documentation: https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login Use /empty to remove.
>
> Me:
>
> https://www.thenameofmysite.com/
>
> BotFather:
>
> Success! Domain updated. /help

But it still renders "Bot domain invalid" instead of telegram login button.

Comment: Try `thenameofmysite.com`

Comment: thenameofmysite.com is enough.

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to create a telegram bot
2. and give the username of the bot, on the https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login page.

3)Then telegram will create a JS code for you. Place it wherever you want it in the HTML file.

4. then send `/setdomain` command to BotFather(@BotFather).
5. then select your bot
6. then send your domain. Eg:- `edupara.lk`

(Telegram Widget only works with HTTPS)

Answer (score 0):

I have a Django server I added to settings

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

this helped solve the problem for me